# Difference between the main goroutine and spawned goroutines of a Go program

Tags: go, goroutine, grpc

When creating a server using `gRPC`, if I start the `gRPC` server in the main process, it can deal with as many as requests (thousands) from clients. However, if I start the server as a goroutine, it can only handle some requests (hundreds) and after get stuck. I have tested and confirmed this with a very simple example, google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld.

Is it because spawned goroutines stack size is very small (2Kbytes), and the main goroutine's much larger? What's the difference between the main goroutine and spawned goroutines?

Example [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/helloworld). Modified parts of the example as follows.

**greeter_server/main.go**

```
func main() {
    go func() {
        lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
        }   
        s := grpc.NewServer()
        pb.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &server{})
        s.Serve(lis)
    }() 

    for {
    }   
}
```

**greeter_client/main.go**

```
func main() {
    // Set up a connection to the server.
    for i := 0; i < 500; i++ {
        conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, grpc.WithInsecure())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
        }
        defer conn.Close()
        c := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)

        for i := 0; i < 500; i++ {
            // Contact the server and print out its response.
            name := defaultName
            if len(os.Args) > 1 {
                name = os.Args[1]
            }
            r, err := c.SayHello(context.Background(), &pb.HelloRequest{Name: name})
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("could not greet: %v", err)
            }
            log.Printf("%d's Greeting: %s", i, r.Message)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They are the same. Can you show an example of exactly what you're doing?

Comment: @JimB Thanks for replying. I have included the example link and the modified code.

Comment: @Amd It's go1.7 linux/amd64

Comment: You have a busy loop in main. Don't do that.

Comment: @JimBI put some sleep code, and it doesn't stuck any more. Could you tell me the reason?

Comment: A busy loop is always a mistake. There's no reason to spin a cpu at 100% just to block. Don't use a for loop at all, wait on something that blocks. There's no reason for the goroutine in this example, just call that code inline. If you really need to block without any operations, you can use an empty `select{}`, but it's not really needed in general.

Answer (score 7):

Why is a Goroutine’s stack infinite:

> One of the key features of Goroutines is their cost; they are cheap to
>   create in terms of initial memory footprint (as opposed to the 1 to 8
>   megabytes with a traditional POSIX thread) and their stack grows and
>   shrinks as necessary. This allows a Goroutine to start with a single
>   4096 byte stack which grows and shrinks as needed without the risk of
>   ever running out.
>
> There is however one detail I have withheld until now, which links the
>   accidental use of a recursive function to a serious case of memory
>   exhaustion for your operating system, and that is, when new stack
>   pages are needed, they are allocated from the heap.
>
> As your infinite function continues to call itself, new stack pages
>   are allocated from the heap, permitting the function to continue to
>   call itself over and over again. Fairly quickly the size of the heap
>   will exceed the amount of free physical memory in your machine, at
>   which point swapping will soon make your machine unusable.
>
> The size of the heap available to Go programs depends on a lot of
>   things, including the architecture of your CPU and your operating
>   system, but it generally represents an amount of memory that exceeds
>   the physical memory of your machine, so your machine is likely to swap
>   heavily before your program ever exhausts its heap.

ref: http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/02/why-is-a-goroutines-stack-infinite

---

Empty loop:

```
for{
}
```

uses 100% of a CPU Core, to wait for some operation depending to the use case you may use:
 - `sync.WaitGroup` like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/eHXwoJCme5)
 - `select {}` like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/2c3FTew-59)
 - channels
 - `time.Sleep`

---

> Is it because spawned goroutines stack size is very small (2Kbytes),
>   and the main goroutine's much larger?

No, you may try these two samples to see the stack limit of goroutines are the same:
one main goroutine on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XzZsmGLgIp),
try second goroutine on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eHXwoJCme5):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go run()
    wg.Wait()
}
func run() {
    s := &S{a: 1, b: 2}
    fmt.Println(s)
    wg.Done()
}

type S struct {
    a, b int
}

// String implements the fmt.Stringer interface
func (s *S) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", s) // Sprintf will call s.String()
}
```

both outputs are the same on the Go Playground:

```
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 250_000_000-byte limit
fatal error: stack overflow
```

outputs on a PC with `8 GB` RAM:

```
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1_000_000_000-byte limit
fatal error: stack overflow
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation!