# What's the best practices to run a background task along with server listening

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm new to Go. Say I have a server listening to HTTP request, and at the same time I need to check Redis notification so I can update data. Below is an example:

```
func checkExpire() {
    for {
        switch msg := pubSubConn.Receive().(type) {
        case redis.Message:
        ...
    }
}

server.ListenAndServe()
```

Does simply putting `checkExpire` into a goroutine a good solution?

```
go func() {
    for {
        switch msg := pubSubConn.Receive().(type) {
        case redis.Message:
        ...
    }
}()
```

Comment: Why not?  That should be perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, goroutines are how you run something concurrently in Go. What else would you do?

Comment: Just be aware that goroutines do not prevent the main process from exiting. You may need to block with `for {}` at the end of main(). *edit* actually server.ListenAndServe should block

Comment: @Plato Sorry, I should put `ListenAndServe` below `checkExpire`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, and remember that `main` is a goroutine too, here is the working code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
func checkExpire() {
    for {
        // do some job
        fmt.Println(time.Now().UTC())
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}

func main() {
    go checkExpire()
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler) // http://127.0.0.1:8080/Go
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Run the code and open your [browser](http://127.0.0.1:8080/Go).

---

And never use Empty loop (`for{}`) see:
[Difference between the main goroutine and spawned goroutines of a Go program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493692/difference-between-the-main-goroutine-and-spawned-goroutines-of-a-go-program)

Empty loop uses 100% of a CPU Core, to wait for some operation depending to the use case you may use:
 - `sync.WaitGroup` like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/eHXwoJCme5)
 - `select {}` like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/2c3FTew-59)
 - channels
 - `time.Sleep`

Comment: Though I've known what to do before you answer, I'll still accept yours. Thx.

Comment: Instead of a for {} loop with a sleep, you might be better off with a `for _ := time.Tick(...) {}` loop and avoid the sleep.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to use empty for in GO to block a go-routine. In fact, sometimes when you want to do periodic tasks, it is your only way to do that. E.g.,
```
for {
 select{
 case <-ticker.C:
 // do something after every ticker time
 case <-anotherChan:
 // do other thing
 }
}
```

Comment: @adonese that's not empty, your loop is perfectly fine and is one of the things the answer suggests. "Empty" here means literally `for {}`.

Comment: I believe the comment i replied to suggested to use `select` instead of a `for{}` for blocking.